# Occurrence indicator for order indicator vs for element

Tags: xml, xsd

What's the difference between

```
<xs:element name="root">
    <xs:complexType>
       <xs:sequence maxOccurs="unbounded">
           <xs:element name="child"/>
       </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

and

```
<xs:element name="root">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="child" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

In the first example the occurrence indicator is applied to `xs:sequence` and the second time it is applied to `xs:element`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your particular case, there is no difference but consider the situation when the sequence contains more than one element:

```
<xs:element name="root">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence maxOccurs="unbounded">
            <xs:element name="child1"/>
            <xs:element name="child2"/>
            <xs:element name="child3"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

compared with:

```
<xs:element name="root">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="child1" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            <xs:element name="child2" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            <xs:element name="child3" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

The first matches any number of sequences of `child1`, `child2`, `child3`:

```
<root>
    <child1/><child2/><child3/>
    <child1/><child2/><child3/>
    <child1/><child2/><child3/>
    …
</root>
```

and the second matches a single sequence that can contain one or more `child1` elements followed by one or more `child2` elements followed by one or more `child3` elements:

```
<root>
    <child1/><child1/><child1/><child1/>
    <child2/><child2/>
    <child3/>
</root>
```

Your schemas have identical effect because a sequence that contains a single element repeated is the same as a repeating sequence that contains a single element. Normally, the sequence repeating and the elements repeating lead to different content models.